# GETH gets out of sync from time to time

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, rpc

GETH tooks 6 days to sync, after that it will get out of sync from time to time. (PC is running with SSD, never shutdown, and network availability is 100% with 500mbps connection).

May I know how will this impact on my RPC call? I do not have this problem with the test net, and I can't test freely in the mainnet.

```
WARN [09-08|13:03:36.588] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block download canceled (requested)"
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 6294224,
  highestBlock: 6294302,
  knownStates: 214533588,
  pulledStates: 214533588,
  startingBlock: 6294202
}
> eth.blockNumber
6294224
> INFO [09-08|13:03:51.349] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=209 percentage=1  elapsed=2m38.113s
```

I do see that from time to time I have problem when trying to query for events from my contract. The RPC will timeout (the node and my software are within the same subnet).